# Create custom Photo browser like photos app in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, vertical-scrolling, photoswipe

I want to create custom photo browser like photos app in iOS 5. Required functionalities are
1) User can swipe left or right to go to previous or next photo
2) User can SCROLL VERTICALLY as my image big in height (composed of several elements. User can see the full size photo)

Resizing the height of photo is not a option.

I can use scroll view but how can I allowed user to SCROLL VERTICALLY & swipe left & right ?
Can anybody tell me how can I create it ? I need it iOS 5+ ONLY.
Any knid of help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked the one as in [this link](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)? But hope it doesn't support vertical scrolling. Better if you modify it.